# Guidelines of How to be a Blockchain Developer by Own Without a CS Degree

Tags: private-blockchain, blockchain-as-a-service

I want to develop my career in blockchain. I am a beginner. Can I have any guidelines on how to become a blockchain developer, please? I have learned just C and the basics of structured programming. I want to learn the Solidity programming language, work on Web 3.0, and make decentralized applications with smart contracts. And I also want to know the uses of different programming languages, including Solidity.

Answer (score 0):

great that you want to join the community!!

I didn't study CS, yet I learned to code Angular/typescript, web2 stuff.

My recommendation would be:

1- Join 1 or 2 communities you like (in my case [Gelato](https://www.gelato.network/) and [Superfluid](https://www.superfluid.finance/))

2- Learn the protocols and start interacting on Discord, asking questions and answering other users' questions when you are capable.

3- At the same, try to participate in online-hackathons, in my case I did 7 on a row, mainly organized by [EthGlobal](https://ethglobal.com/) or (irl is better, but expensive). In hackathons your learnings increase 10x.

4- Once you know the product, try to produce original content (blogs/tutorials/videos), I mean, don't copy and paste for the sick of creating something, but rather something that the protocols may need.

5- After these steps, you will be already known by the community and it is time to apply for intern positions/freelancer support/or if you have a project in mind, apply for grants.

Good luck!!